# How to solve this error in mysql with Join and count?

Tags: mysql, join, count

```
SELECT  b.title ,COUNT(*) AS 'Number_of_books',a2.country 
FROM authors a2 
JOIN authorship a ON a.author_id = a2.author_id 
JOIN books b ON a.book_id = b.book_id 
GROUP BY b.title 
HAVING country IN ("USA","U.S.","America")
```

showing an error message

> SQL Error [1055] [42000]: Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'library.a2.country' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You are `GROUP BY b.title`. What is a2.country output in this aggregated expression if the book author had a different country for the same title?

Comment: Get the number of books written by each American author. Include the first and last names of the author. The tables are books,authorship and authors

Comment: Every non-aggregated column (columns that do not include a `SUM`, `AVG`, `MIN`, `MAX` or `COUNT`) must be included in the `GROUP BY`. You've got two columns that are not aggregated (`b.title` and `a2.country`), but only include `b.title` in the `GROUP BY`. DId you read the words in the error message? They're pretty clear. **Expression #3 of SELECT** would be 'a2.country`, and **is not in GROUP BY clause** seems pretty clear - `a2.country` is "Expressioini #3", and it's **not in GROUP BY**.

Comment: @KenWhite Every non-aggregated column that is not functionally dependent on the group by columns, since 5.7.5, when the mode default was changed to full.

Comment: @philipxy: It's a shame that it's taken that many versions for the change to be made. IMO, there should be no alternative other than full, in compliance with standards.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this method and now it's working

```
 SELECT CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) AS Name, count(title) AS 'No of Books' 
    FROM authors a2 
    JOIN authorship a ON a.author_id = a2.author_id 
    JOIN books b ON a.book_id = b.book_id  
    WHERE a2.country IN ("USA","U.S.","America","United States of America")
    GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: Please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Comment: While this may be the solution you found, it does not answer the question you've asked above, which is about the error in the GROUP BY expression.